# How to not submit form if there are validation fields outstanding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that contains some required fields. An attachment file field, some text boxes including checking email valid and matching and making sure not empty, and selecting a checkbox to ensure user acknowledges terms and conditions.

The problem I have is, if I don't fill out the form and click 'Buy now', it does perform a validation, but it then *redirects* the user to checkout. How can we get it so that the submit button does not redirect, if there are validation present on the form? I use `required` in html and some javascript for email validation.

**HTML FROM**

```
<form id="tcform">    
      <p>
        <b>Attach your CV:</b> (.doc, .docx, .pdf, .txt, .rtf)
        </p>

        <input type="file" id="uploadCV" required/>

        <br/><br/>

        <div class="formcontainer">
        <label for="email"><b>Email:</b></label>
        <input type="input" id="email" name="email"  />

        <p id="resultEmail"></p>


        <label for="email"><b>Confirm Email:</b></label>
        <input type="input" id="confirmEmail" name="confirmEmail"  />

        <p id="resultConfirmEmail"></p>


        <label for="job"><b>Desired Job Position:</b></label>
        <input type="input" id="job" name="job" required />
        </div>

        <br/>
      <p><b>Quantity:</b> 1</p>

      <b class="price">Price:</b> £40
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default buynow" 
      id="checkout-button-sku_xxx" role="link">
      Buy Now
    </button>

      <p class="tcparagraph"><i style="font-size:small">Expected Completion Time: Within 10 working days</i></p>
      <p class="tcparagraph"><input id="field_terms" type="checkbox" required name="terms"> I accept the <u><a href="Terms" id="tclink">Terms and Conditions</a></u></p>
      </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
    <script>
      var file = document.getElementById('uploadCV');

    file.onchange = function(e) {
      var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
      switch (ext) {
        case 'doc':
        case 'docx':
        case 'pdf':
        case 'txt':
        case 'rtf':
          break;
        default:
          alert('Please upload a file that matches any of these file types: .doc, .docx, .pdf, .txt, .rtf');
          this.value = '';
      }
    };

    (function() {
      var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

      var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-sku_xxx');
      checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
        // them to Checkout.
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          items: [{sku: 'sku_xxx', quantity: 1}],

          // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
          // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
          // a successful payment.
          // Instead use one of the strategies described in
          // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
          successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.xxx.com/services/cv-rewrite',
          cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.xxx.com/services/cv-rewrite',
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          if (result.error) {
            // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
            // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
            var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
            displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
          }
        });
      });
    })();

    function validateEmail(email) {
      var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }

    function validate() {
      var $result = $("#resultEmail");
      var $confirmResult = $("#resultConfirmEmail");
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var confirmEmail = $("#confirmEmail").val();
      $result.text("");

      if (validateEmail(email)) {
        if (email == confirmEmail) {
          $confirmResult.text("");
          return true;
      } else {
        $confirmResult.text("Your email and confirm email do not match");
        $confirmResult.css("color", "red");
      }
        } else {
        $result.text("You have not provided a valid email");
        $result.css("color", "red");

        }

      return false;
    }

    $(".buynow").on("click", validate);

    window.onload = function(){
    var label = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
    for (var i = 0; i<label.length; i++) {
      label[i].onclick = function () {
      var el = (this.parentNode);
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
      };
    }
    };        
   </script>
```

Comment: so call your  validation function and run it before you call the stripe api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call your `validate` method before the stripe redirect and you should also check the forms default validation (*[`form.checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_validation_process)*) for things that you do not manually check in your `validate` method.

```js
checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
      // them to Checkout if validations pass.
      const isFormValid = checkoutButton.form.checkValidity() && validate();

      if (!isFormValid) return; // or show message or whatever else you want

      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            items: [{
              sku: 'sku_xxx',
              quantity: 1
            }],

            ...
```

Comment: I think `return false;` takes only effect if you use the event `onSubmit`. On other events you have to fire explecit the submit command.